# C++ Filling a 2d Vector with Structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, 2d

Similar topics have been covered, although I never found an answer.
Relevant snippets of my code:

```
struct Neuron
{
     double weight;
};

typedef vector<Neuron> Layer;

vector<Layer> n_N; // Hopefully creating a vector of layers, which takes in neuron structs
```

then I try to load Neuron structs into n_N in for loop as so:

```
n_N[i][neuronNum].push_back(Neuron);
```

In my undertanding, the [i] is the number in row, then [neuronNum] is the number in column

But I am getting an error: 'struct Neuron' has no member named 'push_back'

Comment: You haven't declared a 2D vector. `std::vector<std::vector<Layer>>` would be one way.

Comment: @JonathanPotter he has actually just indirectly using a `typedef`

Comment: my problem is pushing onto the vector

Comment: Can you show the code where you put stuff into the vectors before this?

Comment: The for loop mentioned is the step where I first put stuff in. I never before loaded n_N with anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to call a function called `push_back()` that is contained within your struct. As you do not have a member function called `push_back()` it is giving you and error. This can be solved by removing the second index in the access specifyer used in the loop. This will work because you are trying to access the vector of `Nuerons` not a member of the vector of `Nuerons`.

e.g.

**Change this:**

```
n_N[i][neuronNum].push_back(Neuron());
```

**To this:**

```
n_N[i].push_back(Neuron());
```

**EDIT: (Credit to M.M for pointing this out)**

The above solution will only work if n_n[i] exists and is not out of the scope of the vector (which would lead to undefined behavior). To solve this issue I would recommend using one of the following for loops.

```
// Range based for loop. (requires c++11 or greater)
for(auto &i: n_N) {i.push_back(Neuron());)

// Standard for loop taking into account the current size of the vector.
for(size_t i = 0; i < n_N.size(); i++) {n_N[i].push_back(Neuron());}

// Iterator for loop.
for(std::vector<std::vector<Neuron> >::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    n_N[it].push_back(Neuron());
}
```

Comment: thank you. After that change, it is expecting a primary expression before ')'

Comment: does it want me to set the weight, or put  parenthesis

Comment: @Sgt.Sarcasm could you show the full error message??

Comment: expected primary-expression before ')' token|

Comment: nvm. it seemed to expect parenthsis. Would you know why?

Comment: n_N[i].push_back(Neuron()); It seemed to want that

Comment: @Sgt.Sarcasm It could be that you need to add a constructor to your struct and call that to create a tempoary object to `push_back()`. Try adding the following function inside your struct `Neuron() {}`. and then calling `n_N[i].push_back(Neuron());`

Comment: This would only work if `n_N[i]` already exists, not sure if OP is aware of that fact

Comment: @M.M This is true however that would be a run time error not a compile error. Worth mentioning though I guess. Will add it into my post.

Comment: I do seem to be ill-informed on the topic. Thank you for the help. I will post back if any other relevant problem comes up

Comment: n_N[i].push_back(Neuron()); Isnt even executed. The program freezes and then it says main.exe has stopped working. It seems to be out of range or something, although I am not sure. Fyi, in the first iteration of the loop, i = 0

Comment: @Sgt.Sarcasm try using one of the for loops above and see if that changes anything (Also add the line `Neuron() {};` inside your Nueron struct if you haven't already), otherwise I suspect it is a problem somewhere else in your code, in which case It is probably time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Clarification: n_N[i].push_back(Neuron()); is reached, although thats where the program stops. I did add the Neuron() {}; into the Neuron struct. I do agree that it is time to learn to debug for me haha